# C - Error while running .exe file that I compiled

Tags: c

I used geany to compile my code and no errors were found.
But when I run the .exe file the program stops working, and I'm not a good programmer, this is a work for school.

My program consists of reading 2 words, in this words its going to count how many letters each one has, and then he divides de number of letters in wordA for number of letters in wordB.

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    float n;

    printf ("Insert first word:\n");

    for(i=0; argv[1][i] != '\0'; i++);

    printf ("Insert second word:\n");

    for(j=0; argv[2][j] != '\0'; j++);

    n=i/j;

    printf("%.4f", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you passing the words as arguments

Comment: You should indent your code, and also paste it rather than copy it. As it stands it does not compile since `Int` is not a defined type.

Comment: Before the first `printf` you should insert:  `if (argc < 3) { printf("Usage: %s <word1> <word2>\n", argv[0]); exit(-1); }`

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
n = i/j;
```

you are performing integer division. So, for example, let's say that `i` is 3 and `j` is 5, then you perform `3/5` which equals `0`.

But I think you are looking to perform `3.0/5.0` and hoping for the answer `0.6`. So you need to perform floating point division. You can force that by casting one of the operands to a float.

```
n = (float)i/j;
```

---

In the question you wrote `Int` rather than `int`. I assumed that was a transcription error when asking the question. But perhaps your real code looks like that. In which case, you'll need to change it to `int` to get it to compile.

The other possible problem you have is that the program expects arguments to be passed on the command line. Are you passing two arguments to your program? In other words you need to execute your program like this:

```
program.exe firstword secondword
```

If you are not passing arguments then you will encounter runtime errors when attempting to access non-existent arguments in `argv[]`. At the very least you should add a check to the program to ensure that `argc==3`.

If you want to read the input from `stdin`, rather than passing command line arguments, use `scanf`.

Comment: +1. `Int` should be `int`. Maybe it's worth to mention that the other variable will be implicitly converted.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Clearly in the real code it is, otherwise the compiler would object.

Comment: @FranciscoOgando I cannot guess what the error is unless you tell me. You say a runtime error?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan program.exe stoped working
then it closes the program

Comment: Read my update please. Did you pass two words as command line arguments? You need to execute the program like this: `program.exe firstword secondword`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if I do like that the program runes smoothly, but my teacher wants me to send him an .exe file
Can't I make it work ?

Comment: You are going to need to use `scanf` to do that. I think your question has been answered now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a conceptual error. Your program (probably) runs fine when called like this:

```
myapp word1 word2
```

But I think you expect it to work like this:

```
myapp
Insert first word:
> word1
Insert second word:
> word2
```

But that's not what `argv` is about. You should look into [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Specifically, the error in the second case is because `argv[1]` is NULL, so `argv[1][i]` is a bad memory access.